# How to resize text button on mobile perspective

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to resize a button in mobile perspective but its text doesn't resize too.
I'm trying to do it in mobile perspective.
Maybe I should use flex in this case.

[The button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIKiV.png)

[how i'm resizing it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaclS.png)

HTML:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="acoes" style=" position: left;" >
          <button mat-stroked-button color="primary" (click)="gerarCertificado(inscricao)" class="width-button">GERAR CERTIFICADO<mat-icon class="md-15">play_arrow</mat-icon> </button>  
      </ng-container>
```

CSS:

```
  @media (max-width: 480px) {
    .width-button{
        max-width: 2%;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modify the `font-size` and the `button` will adjust accordingly.

```css
button {
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

/*
   You would put this code in your media query, but I'm just emulating the
   device with a class for the example.
*/
button.mobile {
  font-size: .8rem;
}
```

```html
<button>Desktop</button>
<button class="mobile">Mobile</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

To resize text change `font-size` value to a smaller one and if content is overflowing from the container than use a `overflow: auto` property

```css
.lbtn{
padding:10px;
font-size:28px;/*Default font-size is 16px*/
}
.sbtn{
padding:0px;
font-size:10px;/*Default font-size is 16px*/
}
```

```html
<button class="lbtn">Large button</button>
<button class="sbtn">Smaller button</button>
```